# How do I simulate a DNS server returning a SERVFAIL in response to a A query?

Tags: dns, java, dnsmasq

**Goal**

When an A query returns an NXDOMAIN response, my java app throws an `UnknownHostException`. I would like to know if a SERVFAIL response from DNS servers caused java to throw this error as well.

**Idea**

- Is it possible to run dnsmasq and make it return a SERVFAIL for any FQDN ?
- Is it simple enough to write a listener on port 53 to listen for UDP requests and return a SERVFAIL ?

Comment: I'm sure dnsmasq would do that if you pointed it to an unreachable upstream `--server`, as would Bind9 and Unbound. One of the SERVFAIL meanings is "I couldn't reach the upstream server."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. As Java programmer, I would point you to Java implementation of a simple DNS server:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnsjava/

Take it, edit the source to return SERVFAIL, shutdown your DNS service, compile and run dnsjava

Comment: Sound like what I want, let me take a look at the source first.